# Get Local Path from Share Name using WNetGetResourceInformation

Tags: c, windows, winapi, network-programming

I am trying to get the Local Path from a Share Name. For example, let's say that SERVER1 shares C:\FOLDER1 as "MYSHARE".

The client machine maps drive M: to \\SERVER1\MYSHARE. On the client machine I want to detect that MYSHARE maps to C:\FOLDER1 on SERVER1.

I am able to get this information using NetShareGetInfo, but now I am trying to get the information using the WNet APIs, because NetShareGetInfo requires Administrative permissions.

I tried using WNetGetResourceInformation in the example specified [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385369%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

I specified lpRemoteName as "\\server1\myshare". The call to WNetGetResourceInformation is successful, however, lpLocalName and the variable string portion, lplpSystem, both return NULL.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Winnetwk.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "mpr.lib")
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    DWORD sz = sizeof(NETRESOURCE);
    NETRESOURCE nr = {0};
    LPTSTR ptr = NULL;
    LPNETRESOURCE buf = NULL;
    DWORD rc;
    nr.dwScope = RESOURCE_GLOBALNET;    // also tried other values
    nr.dwType = RESOURCETYPE_DISK;
    nr.lpRemoteName = argv[1];
    buf = malloc(sz);
    while ((rc = WNetGetResourceInformation(&nr, buf, &sz, &ptr)) == ERROR_MORE_DATA)
    {
        buf = realloc(buf, sz);
    }
    printf("WNetGetResourceInformation=%d Size=%d\n", rc, sz);
    if (rc == 0)
    {
        printf("LocalName={%s} RemoteName={%s} Provider={%s}\n", buf->lpLocalName, buf->lpRemoteName, buf->lpProvider);
        printf("Variable={%s}\n", ptr);
        free(buf);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to get this information using the WNet APIs, and am I using the right one?

Thanks.

Comment: The name of the share is `\\server1\myshare`, not `\server1\myshare` (note the two leading backslash characters).

Comment: That was just a typo in the article above. Apparently StackOverflow treats backslash as an escape character. In my test it was correctly formulated.

Comment: I would not expect a non-admin user to be allowed to retrieve this kind of information remotely... Have you tried with WMI?

Comment: I did try it as an Admin as well, with the same results. How would I get that information using WMI?